# command button not working inside datatable in JSF 1.2

Tags: jsf, datatable, jsf-1.2

I am new to JSF 1.2 and In my office, I have to only work on JSF 1.2, not any higher version. When I am creating datatable in a .jspx file the data is displaying but when I add any  inside datatable the button doesn't work. Some say that you have to set the scope to view but in a JSF 1.2 there isn't any view scope. Can anyone please help me with this?

This is in Eclipse IDE for Web Developer with JSF 1.2._07 with Tomcat 7.

**View.jspx**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<jsp:root xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" version="2.0">
    <jsp:directive.page language="java"
        contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" />
    <jsp:text>
        <![CDATA[ <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?> ]]>
    </jsp:text>
    <jsp:text>
        <![CDATA[ <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> ]]>
    </jsp:text>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
**<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<title>View Data</title>
</head>
<body>
<f:view>

    <table border="2" cellpadding = "10" cellspacing = "1">
    <tr>
    <td><f:facet name="header">ID</f:facet></td>    
    <td><f:facet name="header">Roll No</f:facet></td>
    <td><f:facet name="header">Name</f:facet></td>
    <td><f:facet name="header">Email</f:facet></td>
    <td><f:facet name="header">Phone</f:facet></td>
    <td><f:facet name="header">Username</f:facet></td>
    <td><f:facet name="header">Password</f:facet></td>
    </tr>
    </table>

    <h:dataTable binding="#{table}" var="data" value="#{studentBean.dataFromDB}" border="2" cellpadding = "10" cellspacing = "1">
    <h:column >
        <h:outputText value=" #{data.id}"></h:outputText> 
    </h:column>

    <h:column >
        <h:outputText value=" #{data.roll}"></h:outputText> 
    </h:column>

    <h:column >
        <h:outputText value=" #{data.name}"></h:outputText> 
    </h:column>

    <h:column >
        <h:outputText value=" #{data.email}"></h:outputText>
    </h:column>

    <h:column >
        <h:outputText value=" #{data.phone}"></h:outputText>
    </h:column> 

    <h:column >
        <h:outputText value=" #{data.username}"></h:outputText> 
    </h:column>

    <h:column >
        <h:outputText value=" #{data.password}"></h:outputText> 
    </h:column>

    <h:column>
        <h:commandButton value="Update" action="#{studentBean.backLogin}"></h:commandButton>
    </h:column>

    </h:dataTable>

</f:view>
</body>
</html>
</jsp:root>
```

**StudentBean.java**

```
package com.crud.jsf;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

import com.crud.service.ConnectionClass;



public class StudentBean {

    private int id;
    private String roll,name,email,phone,username,password;
    private List dataFromDB;


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getRoll() {
        return roll;
    }
    public void setRoll(String roll) {
        this.roll = roll;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }
    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public List getDataFromDB() {
        return dataFromDB;
    }

    ConnectionClass cc = new ConnectionClass();
    @PostConstruct
    public void init()
    {
        dataFromDB = cc.getUserList();
    }

    public String login()
    {
        boolean valid = cc.validate(username, password);
        if(valid)
        {
            return "view";
        }
        else
        {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN,
            "Incorrect username or password","Please enter correct Username and Password!!"));
            return "login";
        }
    }

    public String register()
    {
        return "register";
    }


    public String addUser(StudentBean S)
    {
        boolean added = cc.add(S);

        if(added)
        {   
            FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Registered Successfull!!"));
            return "login";
        }
        else
        {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN,
                    "Error","Please enter all the details!!"));
                    return "register";
        }

    }

    public String backLogin()
    {
        return "login";
    }

public String delete(int id)

    {   
        System.out.println(id);
        boolean valid = cc.delete(id);
        if(valid)
        {
            return "view";
        }
        else
        {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN,
            "Error","Please try again!!!"));
            return "error";
        }

    }

}
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>CrudJSF</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>faces/login.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <context-param>
    <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
    <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
</web-app>
```

**faces-config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<faces-config
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_1_2.xsd"
    version="1.2">

    <managed-bean>
    <display-name>Student</display-name>
    <managed-bean-name>studentBean</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>com.crud.jsf.StudentBean</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>application</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>

    <navigation-rule>
    <display-name>Login</display-name>
    <from-view-id>/login.jsp</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
    <from-outcome>view</from-outcome>
    <to-view-id>/view.jspx</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
    <navigation-case>
    <from-outcome>login</from-outcome>
    <to-view-id>/login.jsp</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
    <navigation-case>
    <from-outcome>register</from-outcome>
    <to-view-id>/register.jsp</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>


    <navigation-rule>
    <display-name>Register</display-name>
    <from-view-id>/register.jsp</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
    <from-outcome>login</from-outcome>
    <to-view-id>/login.jsp</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
    <navigation-case>
    <from-outcome>register</from-outcome>
    <to-view-id>/register.jsp</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>

    <navigation-rule>
    <display-name>View</display-name>
    <from-view-id>/view.jspx</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
    <from-outcome>view</from-outcome>
    <to-view-id>/view.jspx</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
    <navigation-case>
    <from-outcome>error</from-outcome>
    <to-view-id>/view.jspx</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
    <navigation-case>
    <from-outcome>login</from-outcome>
    <to-view-id>/login.jsp</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>
</faces-config>
```

First I have set the scope to session then I have tried to make it application and still getting same result as my h:commandbutton isn't working....!
        [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/haNpr.png)

Comment: butting the button outside the datatable works? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/commandbutton-commandlink-ajax-action-listener-method-not-invoked-or-input-value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of Command button I have user Command Link for passing a ID to Bean Class and get the desired output.

```
<h:commandLink id="deleteLink" action="#{studentBean.delete}">
        <h:outputText value="Delete"></h:outputText>
        <f:param name="id" value="#{data.id}"></f:param>
```